# Login with OTP(textlocal) in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, node-modules, one-time-password

I am trying to create a login with otp in nodejs using textlocal api.I am able to send otp to the number by the below code, how can I verify that OTP and retur login successfull.

```
var http = require('http');
var urlencode = require('urlencode');
var msg='test';
var number='91*******';
var username='username';
var hash='api'; // The hash key could be found under Help->All Documentation->Your hash key. Alternatively you can use your Textlocal password in plain text.
var sender='SStion';
var data='username='+username+'&hash='+hash+'&sender='+sender+'&numbers='+number+'&message='+msg
var options = {
 host: 'api.textlocal.in',
 path: '/send?'+data
};
callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';
  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
  str += chunk;
  });
  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
  console.log(str);
  });
}
//console.log('hello js'))
http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to save otp with expiry datetime (for example: otp is valid for next 5 min) in your database for that user ,
2. when user enter otp , you have to compare user entered otp with saved otp
3. also compare current datetime with otp expiry datetime
4. if otp not matched show "Invalid OTP"
5. if current datetime is greater than otp expiry datetime  then show "otp expired"
6. if entered otp == database otp && current datetime < otp expiry datetime then show success message OTP verified & redirect to dashboard page

Comment: but everytime user login with otp i will need to update that for example at first time i will need to insert the otp and after that i will need to update the otp everytime the user login or maybe i was thinking something without db involve